# Adding an AutoCompleteTextEditPreference to Android Preferences keeps crashing

Tags: android

I'm having an issue adding a Custom Preference to my app. The app runs, but the Preferences View crashes immediately on its creation. The logcat says it can't start the activity. Its an

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class com.example.app.AutoCompletePreference.
```

There is also a **ClassNotFoundException** on **AutoCompletePreference**.

I believe it has something to do with how the Preference is declared.

Does it need to be put in an intent somewhere? Or somewhere in the Manifest?

EDIT:

Here are the files on Gist:

myapppreferences.xml - the preferences display
https://gist.github.com/jmslobodsky/116f7ce3f74e3e9e557c

AppPreferencesActivity.java - the Preferences Activity
https://gist.github.com/jmslobodsky/501162472551fa78528d

Comment: Pless paste relevant code.

Comment: where is the class `AutoCompletePreference` ? is it included in your app?